# How to hide success page in Django

Tags: python, html, django, redirect

I'd like to know if anyone knows:

For example, I have a form that user fills in, and when he submits, the page will redirect to "thank you" page. Everything works fine. In urls.py I had this line pointing that the page exists:

```
url(r'^thankyou/$', 'render_form'),
```

But then, when I type in url mysite.com/thankyou/, the page "Thank you" appears... But I need it to appear only when I submit a form and hide it when user tries to open it directly.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put something in the session in your form handling view before redirecting, and check it in the thank-you URL: if it's not there, then return a 403 error. Something like:

```
def form_handling_view(request):
    if request.POST:
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ... handle the form ...
            request.session['form_posted'] = True
            return redirect('thank_you')

def thank_you(request):
    if not request.session.pop('form_posted', False):
        return HttpResponseForbidden('not permitted')
    ... render thank_you page ...
```

Note I'm using `pop` in thank_you to ensure that the key is deleted from the session no matter what.

Comment: yes it works, but i had to edit some conditions in thank_you method. thank you very much Daniel.